# Show Custom camera in shape of image with custom filters ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, core-graphics, core-image

I am creating a feature like open front camera in custom image shape. I am not sure how exactly this should be achieved. I have googled enough to find out the way to achieve it. But no success yet.

I have tried to make a layer using AVCapture session & add into Image layer but it takes whole square frame of image not takes in image shape only by ignoring transparent pixels.

This is something what i need to achieve like : http://apple.co/2h7Oe8L. Please let me know if anything library or framework available or by using core features of Objective C i can do it.

Any reference or hint will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried. Have you tried putting your AVCapture layer below a view with a hole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding ***AVCapture*** layer into image layer add it to another view and then set the image in the `mask` property of that view. i.e:

```
let view = UIView()
view.layer.addSublayer(avCaptureLayer)
view.mask = image

addSubview(view)
```

- You need to add the new view to the hierarchy, but the image doesn't.
- You can use auto layout to position and resize the new view, but the image needs be resized/repositioned directly in its frame